# jQuery to change img src based on href

Tags: jquery

I have four or five thumbnails next to a full-size image. When I click the thumbnail, I just want it to replace the full-size image.

Thumbnail:

```
<a href="newimage.jpg" class="enlarge"><img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="thumbnail" /></a>
```

Fullsize:

```
<div id="folio-detail">
<img id="fullImage" src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
        $("a.enlarge").live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("img#fullImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
         });
    });
```

This isn't working ... any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference to jQuery needs to come before your code so that the jQuery (`$`) function is defined. I've slightly changed your code too (which was working), but hopefully the change makes it clearer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("a.enlarge").live('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var href = this.href;
       $("#fullImage").attr("src", href);
    });
});
</script>
```

**[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/A8y58/)**

Comment: It wasn't me. I was busy trying to work out why "this.href" was any different from "$(this).attr("src", href)". Haven't you just replaced one piece of code with an equivalent piece? http://jsfiddle.net/hBt6V/

Comment: This is not an answer. It's just changing his code into something that does exactly the same thing. There is no difference in functionality between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work. I have put it into JSFiddle and it works, just have a look [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8K2Xy/).

Are you sure you included the JQuery library?

Comment: By the way, don't pay attention to the images I used. They were just the first two to pop up when I googled for some. But it proves that the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct.  Have you tried alerting what is happening?  I.e. above the e.preventDefault put "alert('here')".  Also alert the clicked on href.  If both of those are correct, try changing out the full image selector to '#folio-detail img'.

Can you also look at the changing source code (i.e Firebug/Developer tools) to see if anything is changing?